# Include a single field from a related model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, I have an Organization model, I use UserExtension model to extend the standard User model. The UserExtension provides a foreign key to Organization.

I want to expose a single field from Organization in the user API. An example user will look sort of like this

`{
  'username': 'test',
  'org_uuid': '4AD6636C-8DC6-49BA-908C-4099C7DB0B81',
  ... a bunch of other fields...
}`

And I want to be able to pass this to create/update APIs so I can set/change what organization the user belongs to. I know I can override to_representation() and to_internal_value(), but it seems like an overkill for something like this. How do I include a single field from a related model?

Comment: do you want to add organizer field in your UserExtension serializer  or add username field into your Organizer serializer?

Comment: Neither. I was a User serializer to have an org_id field corresponding to a field in UserExtension. In regular django model syntax I would use user__userextension__org__uuid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `org_uuid` field in your `UserExtensionSerializer` with a [`source` argument.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) In the `source` argument, we will use dotted notation to traverse to the `org_uuid` attribute in the related `organisation` object.

```
class UserExtensionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    org_uuid = serializers.UUIDField(source='organisation.org_uuid') # define the field
```

In case of serialization, your serialized representation of object will contain a key `org_uuid` which will contain the value of `org_uuid` attribute from the corresponding `organisation` object.

In case of create/update, you can access the `org_uuid` value in the `serializer.validated_data`.

Comment: Thanks this was pretty much what I was looking for. In my case, it was  

 `org_uuid = serializers.UUIDField(source='userextension.org.uuid')`

Answer (score 0):

In the user serializer you can add org serializer and modify the to_representation method to get the required format.

Comment: Overriding to_representation seems like an overkill. Besides, I don't want just some org, I want a particular org that corresponds to this user.

Comment: then maybe override the view and get the data from serializer and update the data dictionary with whatever data you need.